# Mysql - How to make an addition on two fields from distinct tables in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have two tables

```
Invoices
  id
  discount
  voucher_id
  ...

Vouchers
  id
  discount  
  ...
```

My goal is not to get the count of invoices where the total discount is equal to 100.

I tried

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM invoices 
LEFT JOIN vouchers ON invoices.voucher_id = vouchers.id
WHERE (invoices.discount + vouchers.discount) = 100
```

But this will return an empty result, and in my DB, I have fields that respects that where clause.

Comment: Your logic is very correct but plz dont use inner join rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will only bring back invoices that have a voucher discount because you have included `vouchers.discount` in your `WHERE` clause.

Assuming that not all invoices have a voucher_id value (from the fact that you are using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`) & also assuming that an invoice can only ever have one voucher.....

```
select count(*) from
 (
  SELECT invoices.discount+ifnull(vouchers.discount,0) as total_discount
  FROM invoices 
  LEFT JOIN vouchers ON invoices.voucher_id = vouchers.id
 ) t
where total_discount = 100;
```

Comment: Right, using if will make the difference, thanks a lot. By the way, using if in where clause will also work